# How to pass this type auto function?

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, auto

I'm trying to pass this auto function to another function, but apparently I can't pass an auto type, so can I change it to whatever the type actually is in order to pass it? By googling I read that you can use templates, but we didn't go over them in my class yet so I'd rather find a more beginner way of doing it if there is one.

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> yPosition(lowBounds, 23);    
auto randY = std::bind(yPosition, std::ref(engine));

void my_function(??? randY)
{
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> ```
> template <class F, class... Args>
> /*unspecified*/ bind( F&& f, Args&&... args );
> ```

The type you're looking for is unspecified. It is, of course, an actual type, but it's whatever your standard library chose, and not something you can portably spell out. And even if you could, it's probably an horrendeous mess of nested meta-templates which you wouldn't *want* to spell out.
Thanks, `auto` !

Your only solution is to make `my_function` a template :

```
template <class RandY>
void my_function(RandY &&randY) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

The way to pass an auto type *is* to use templates. There is no alternative†

```
template <typename F>
void my_function(F randY)
{ ... }
```

---

<sub>†Technically there is a proposal in concepts to allow `my_function(auto randY)`, but that is just a proposal.</sub>

Comment: But what is the auto type in this case? can't I change it to whatever type it actually is? I found it online using auto so I don't know what the auto is in place of.

Comment: @AustinMW You don't know what the type actually is. See [Quentin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728071/2069064).

Comment: Ah ok, I thought there was a specific type that I just didn't happen to know.

Comment: there is a specific type that you are not supposed to know or care about. As Quentin says above the the type is a "horrendous mess of nested meta-templates", but it is nonetheless a specific type. You could find out the exact type (via typeof or using an IDE), and you could write it down, it is just rarely the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers state you need to use a template if you want the function to take the exact same type that falls out of the bind.

However if you just want a way to call the bound function inside of `my_function` you can use `std::function<>`. `std::function` uses *type-erasure* to abstract away the full type, leaving you with a generic way to call whatever function-like type you put in it. Of course `std::function` incurs a (small) run-time overhead.

```
void my_function(std::function<int()> randY) { 
   //... 
   int y = randY();
   //...
}
```